# running select in simpledb with node.js giving error

Tags: node.js, amazon-simpledb

I am running following code :
https://github.com/rjrodger/simpledb

```
var simpledb = require('simpledb');
var sys = require('sys');
sdb  = new simpledb.SimpleDB({keyid:'kye'
                    ,secret:'mysectkey'});
var str="select  *  from youngib where createdon is not null  order by createdon desc limit 10";                    
sdb.select (str,  function( error, result ) {
        console.log('attr1 = '+sys.inspect(error));
        console.log('result = '+sys.inspect(result));
    });
```

if i run this in seperate file it run but if i run in my project it gives me this error ,why this error coming?

```
{ Code: 'SignatureDoesNotMatch',
  Message: 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.' }
```

the problem was that there i have declare

```
Array.prototype.in_array = function(p_val) {
    for(var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
        if(this[i] == p_val) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

due to this it was not executing the simpledb , i don't know why, if you know please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you extend `Array.prototype` you can get issues with `for ... in` loops.

For example:

```
Array.prototype.foo = 42;
var array = [1,2,3];
for (var index in array) {
    console.log(index + "," + array[index]);
    // logs 0,1 1,2 2,3 foo,42
}
```

The for in loop iterates over all properties. So basically your 3rd party code makes the assumption you have not extend on `Array.prototype`.

Extending native prototypes is bad practice for these reasons.

As for your `in_array` method you could use

```
var contains = someArray.some(function(val) {
    return val === p_val;
});
```

instead.